# Need help finding datasheet for Mitsubishi Electric AA11SB6C-ADFD TFT

Tags: lcd, datasheet, pinout

Searching datasheet for Mitsubishi Electric AA11SB6C-ADFD LCD display.
This LCD is discontinued product, no information on official site.
Already tried sites like datasheetarchive, alldatasheet. Still no luck.

Even just pinout for TTL connector on this display will be much help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some searching around and it looks like this LCD is just too ancient.  I can't find any documentation for it.

I wouldn't even suggest wasting your time with contacting the manufacturer.  Corporations like Mitsubishi Electric is a subsidiary of the whole conglomerate and will buy parts from other no-name companies.  Even if you can salvage the name of this company, they are as silent as a graveyard when talking to end consumers because that is not who they market to.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer you are probably looking for but I suggest contacting the manufacturer.  When I cannot find the datasheet or other information for a part they are usually very helpful.  It may take a while though before you get a response.

Comment: They rarely reply. Especially the eastern ones (eg. china).